# Strange Issue: JSON Field Doesn't Correspond to Property Name

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm encountering an issue while handling JSON data, attempting to match the fields in the JSON to properties within a Java class. I have a JSON format like this:

```json
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "...",
    "expires_in": 604799,
    "scope": "all",
    "jti": "..."
}
```

I've created a Java class JwtToken to map this JSON structure, but I'm facing a problem. I need to align the fields in the JSON with the properties in the Java class. For instance, access_token should map to the accessToken property, token_type to tokenType, and so forth.

My Java class looks something like this:

```java
@Data
public class JwtToken {
    /**
     * access_token
     */
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String access_token;
    /**
     * token类型
     */
    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String token_type;
    /**
     * refresh_token
     */
    @JsonProperty("refresh_token")
    private String refresh_token;
    /**
     * 过期时间
     */
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Long expires_in;
    /**
     * token 的范围
     */
    private String scope;
    /**
     * 颁发的凭证
     */
    private String jti;
}
```

The issue arises when I change property names to camel case (e.g., access_token to accessToken). Spring throws an exception during deserialization. The error message is as follows:

> Error while extracting response for type [class com.casey.feign.JwtToken] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "access_token" (class com.casey.feign.JwtToken), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "access_token" (class com.casey.feign.JwtToken), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "tokenType", "scope", "accessToken", "expiresIn", "refreshToken", "jti"])\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.casey.feign.JwtToken["access_token"])

Even though I've explicitly specified the JSON field names using @JsonProperty annotation, it seems not to work in this scenario. Could there be a reason causing this issue? Are there any other configurations or methods to resolve this problem?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Hi, your code looks fine and it worked. I have implemented the same using Spring Boot Find the below github link
https://github.com/AjinkyaKarode10/Dec2023.git
Please have a look at lombok dependency, & spring-boot-web dependency

Comment: Hi, thank u for your help. I think my dependency are just as yours. I've uploaded part of my project here in the link github.com/kiwi6185/Dec2023. I tried the same version of Spring Boot as urs but I have to adjust other methods...

Comment: Great !
Please mention the changes done by you in the answer so that it can help others

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the issue hasn't been resolved yet. I simply adjusted the member attribute names temporarily to match the database field names, rather than following Java naming conventions. I'll update the code and provide more details once the problem is resolved.